# Angular 4.0 router NavigationStart events do not contain url member

Tags: angular, events, router

I have just upgraded my angualr-cli project to Angualr 4.0, and local Typescript@2.3.4, the following code in my **app.component.ts** was working fine before the upgrade:

Now the url memeber is no longer available in the event

```
    router.events.filter(event => event instanceof NavigationStart)
      .subscribe(e => {
         this.currentUrl = e.url; // Error here 'url is not defined in Event'
           console.log("Now route", e.toString()); // logs something like NavigationStart(id: 1, url:'/my-url') as a string
    })
```

How can I get the 'url' member from the 'e' without having to manipulate the string returned by 'e.toString()' of the NavigationStart class.

Is there a different way to get the current and previous routes as a string from the Router when user navigates?, please advice on this.

My understanding is very little and would appreciate some help with this one.

Answer (score 3):

Try this to get the previous and the next url :

```
 this.router.events
      .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
      .pairwise()
      .subscribe((value: [NavigationEnd, NavigationEnd]) => {

        let previousUrl = value[0].url;
        let nextUrl = value[1].url;
      });
```

Imports to use :

```
import "rxjs/add/operator/filter";
import "rxjs/add/operator/pairwise";
```

Comment: can you share any source that i can read more about this? do you think this code will work also for the next angular release?